# stash is not getting the files in subfolder

Tags: jenkins, ant, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to stash all files named "*myFiles* in a subfolder named "MyFolder", can't figure out why this isn't working:

```
stash name: "mystash", includes: '**/*myFiles*'
```

I verified this files exist, the case and name is correct, but stash is still not working. When I unstash I only get "MyFolder" and its empty. From what I understand stash uses ant glob syntax? Is my syntax wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested using the pipeline below and works

```
node {
    ansiColor('xterm') {
        stage("test") {
           sh 'mkdir bla && cd bla && touch blabmyFiles34 && touch nothing'
           sh 'touch 12myFiles'
           sh 'touch test'
           sh 'touch 13myFiles'
           sh 'touch 12myFiles3232'
           sh 'ls -la'
           stash name: "mystash", includes: '**/*myFiles*'
       }
       stage("files") {
           sh 'rm -rf *'
           unstash name: "mystash"
           sh 'ls -la'
           sh 'ls -la bla' 
       }
   }
}
```

this is the jenkins output:

```
[Pipeline] node
Running on US-EAST-1Ubuntu (i-) in /home/ubuntu/workspace/test-stash
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] ansiColor
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (test)
[Pipeline] sh
[test-stash] Running shell script
+ mkdir bla
+ cd bla
+ touch blabmyFiles34
+ touch nothing
[Pipeline] sh
[test-stash] Running shell script
+ touch 12myFiles
[Pipeline] sh
[test-carlos-stash] Running shell script
+ touch test
[Pipeline] sh
[test-carlos-stash] Running shell script
+ touch 13myFiles
[Pipeline] sh
[test-carlos-stash] Running shell script
+ touch 12myFiles3232
[Pipeline] sh
[test-stash] Running shell script
+ ls -la
total 12
drwxrwxr-x  3 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Feb 15 11:43 .
drwxrwxr-x 14 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Feb 15 11:36 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu    0 Feb 15 11:37 12myfiles
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu    0 Feb 15 11:43 12myFiles
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu    0 Feb 15 11:43 12myFiles3232
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu    0 Feb 15 11:43 13myFiles
drwxrwxr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Feb 15 11:43 bla
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu    0 Feb 15 11:43 test
[Pipeline] stash
Stashed 4 file(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (files)
[Pipeline] sh
[test-stash] Running shell script
+ rm -rf 12myFiles 12myFiles3232 12myfiles 13myFiles bla test
[Pipeline] unstash
[Pipeline] sh
[test-stash] Running shell script
+ ls -la
total 12
drwxrwxr-x  3 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Feb 15 11:43 .
drwxrwxr-x 14 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Feb 15 11:36 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu    0 Feb 15 11:43 12myFiles
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu    0 Feb 15 11:43 12myFiles3232
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu    0 Feb 15 11:43 13myFiles
drwxrwxr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Feb 15 11:43 bla
[Pipeline] sh
[test-stash] Running shell script
+ ls -la bla
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Feb 15 11:43 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Feb 15 11:43 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu    0 Feb 15 11:43 blabmyFiles34
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // ansiColor
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

is that what you are looking for?

Comment: nvm this was something crazy about my ls command not showing me everything in the console output!